# PHP Script for Wordpress: Creating CPTs with CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, import, advanced-custom-fields

i just started learning php. I tried to create a script, which goes through an CSV and creates a CPT for each row in my Wordpress-System. Each column should fill the title/ACF-Fields.

Code:

```
$csv_file_path = 'link-to-csv';

function create_wp_cpt_from_csv() {
    global $csv_file_path;
    if (($handle = fopen($csv_file_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            $post = array(
                'post_title' => $data[0],
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'sorten'
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
            update_field('acf_1', $data[1], $post_id);
            update_field('acf_2', $data[2], $post_id);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

add_action('init', 'create_link_to_import_csv');

function create_link_to_import_csv() {
    add_menu_page( 'Import CSV', 'Import CSV', 'manage_options', 'import_csv', 'import_csv_function');
}

function import_csv_function(){
    create_wp_cpt_from_csv();
}
```

I changed the link of the csv.

I implemented this code in my functions.php. Unfortunately, whenever i click on the "Import CSV" button, nothing happens.

Comment: I suggest including the javascript/html from the import CSV button

Comment: There is no javascript/html.


`add_action('init', 'create_link_to_import_csv');

function create_link_to_import_csv() {
    add_menu_page( 'Import CSV', 'Import CSV', 'manage_options', 'import_csv', 'import_csv_function');
}

function import_csv_function(){
    create_wp_cpt_from_csv();
}`


This part of my code creates a button in my wordpress-backend. I thought this would be enough to run the function via clicking on the button in the backend.

Comment: First guess would be that it does not actually find your CSV file. The execution context of this is _not_ the directory where the `functions.php` is located. Have you tried to specify the full, absolute path from the file system root?

Comment: Or is that supposed to be a URL instead of a file system path to begin with? (Asking, because you say "link", which is a bit ambiguous.) In that case, `allow_url_fopen` would have to be active in your PHP config, otherwise fopen will not be able to read from this URL.

Comment: I changed the dir of the csv to the same as the functions.php. And changed the first line of code to:

`$csv_file_path = 'test.csv';`

Still nothing happens.